# Program teeminated when it encounters Scanner

Tags: java

Following is my code snippet

```
public int[] factoring(){
        int factors[]=new int[10];
        int i=1,k=0,n;


            System.out.println("Please enter n");
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        n=sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println(n);
        while(i<=n){
        if(n%i==0){
            factors[k]=i;
            System.out.println(factors[k]);
            k++;
            }
        i++;
        }
        return factors;

    }
```

I'm not able to enter value for n, the program is terminating when it encountered Scanner object creation.

Comment: Is there a stack trace or error reported?  If so, add it to the question.

Comment: I don't think your problem is actually caused by this method.  Can you show your entire program please?  Also, the stack trace is pretty much essential if you want help with something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean it fails when you try to compile the program with "javac".  If so, you need to import the scanner class.  Add

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

at the appropiate place in your program.

Good luck!

Comment: "The program is terminating" doesn't usually mean "this won't compile".  This is very unlikely to be correct.

Comment: I have included in the original program, but I have the same problem.

Comment: I think you're going to have to post the entire program.  The code snippet you've posted works fine for me.

Comment: Is there any chance that we get this problem in our IDE

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not adding this to the comments, but I don't know how to post code in comments.

It's unlikely it's the IDE, especially if you're using Eclipse or Netbeans.  Though anything's possible at this point, and you may have a corrupt file or something on your machine.

Does this code work?

```
package testscanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("n = " + n);
    }

}
```

Make sure when you enter a number that the cursor is located at "Enter a number:" and not in the code window.

Also, is there some reason you're not posting the entire class or the entire error message?  Cut and paste makes it easy.  I appreciate you're trying to reduce it to the relevant code, but the code you've posted so far doesn't have the error.

Good luck!